# Storing Json response element in a variable using Karate

Tags: rest, karate

Storing the following json response in a variable

`[{"Resort":"SANRS","ResvNameID":14396162,"ConfirmationNo":"86749976"},
{"Resort":"SANRS","ResvNameID":13123123,"ConfirmationNo":"98932423"}]`

And def allres = response
And print allres.reservations[0].ResvNameID does not print anything? What's wrong here?

Comment: I think Idid accept it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON path is wrong.

Try:

`* print allres[0].ResvNameID`

Output:

`[print] 14396162`